# Solve $(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2-7x+12}= 1$.

Tags: quadratics, problem-solving, integers

What are all the possible values of $x$ if $(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2-7x+12}= 1$.  I have already found three answers: 4, 3, and 1, however, apparently there are more possibilities. I don't know how to figure this out so it would be extremely appreciated if someone found the other possibilities and showed me how to do it.

Comment: Please check the equation. The parentheses don't balance. (While you're editing, put the equation into the title of your question.)

Comment: I have adjusted the problem's typesetting to be consistent with the $4,3,1$ solutions given.

Comment: $x^2-7x+12 = (x-3)(x-4)$

Comment: For positive $x^2-5x+5$ your solutions are the only ones. The question is whether negative $x^2-5x+5$ is allowed.

Comment: No, wait. For $x^2-5x+5 < 0$ for $x=3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

> $(-1)^{k}=1$ (if $k$ is an even integer).
>
> In other words, you forgot the case that $x^2-5x+5=-1.$

Solving this, we get $x^2-5x+6=0\rightarrow x=2,3.$

We check that the exponent is even.

If $x=3,$ then $(x-3)(x-4)=0.$

If $x=2,$ then $(-1)(-2)=2.$

Either way, it is even, so both solutions are valid.

All solutions are $ 1,2,3,4$.

Comment: So how would you use this to get the other possibilities? Sorry, I'm still quite confused.

Comment: Solve for $x^2-5x+5=-1$ and check the exponent is even.

Comment: In particular ~ there are three possibilities: The exponent is $0,$ the base is $1/-1.$
$-1$ is the case that was not included in the solution.

Comment: wait how did you get (x^2)−5x+5=−1?

Comment: $x^2-5x+5$ is the base, and we are setting it equal to $-1.$

Comment: The question is whether this is allowed because $a^x$ as a function of $x$ is only defined for $a > 0$.

Comment: @Julie You should actually answer this question yourself. Do you just have this equation or any more information? For example, is the question to find all *integer values* of $x$ solving the equation?

Comment: @JasonKim Recently in an entrance exam it was asked to explain why these are all solutions and there is no other(in first step asked to find the solutions). I have found all, but was not able to explain properly(I have explained by taking $\log$ both side) why these are all solutions and there are no other. Can you explain : `How we are sure there are no other solutions`?